# Pthread Programming: Segmentation Fault: 11 while using mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to use  Mutex to lock a region of code. I have tried to post as much code as I could.

```
//Global Variables
int sum;
long long fact=1;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_t id1,id2;

void *thread_1_And_2(void *accept_1)
{
    //Accepting Input
    int *a_ptr = (int*) accept_1;
    int a= *a_ptr;

    //Locking the resource
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    //Returning the process ID that is working right now!
    pthread_t my_current_id;
    my_current_id= pthread_self();

    if((pthread_equal(id1,my_current_id))>0)
    {

        printf("\nI am Thread 1: Processing Sum\n");

        printf("\n I am in Thread 1 \n");
        for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {
        sum= sum+i;
        }
    }
    else if((pthread_equal(id2, my_current_id))>0)
    {
        printf("\nI am Thread 2: Processing Factorial\n");
        if (a<0)
        {
            printf("\n Error! Factorial of Negative number not possible \n");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=a; i++)
            {
            fact=fact*i;
            }
        }
    }

    //Unlocking the Mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

And in the main fucntion it is Initialised and called as follows:

```
printf("\n Input for thread_1:\n");
int store_1; //= atoi(argv[1]);
printf("\nEnter number up to which you want a sum of natural numbers\n");
scanf("%d", &store_1);

printf("\nInput for thread_2:\n");
int store_2; //= atoi(argv[2]);
printf("\nEnter number whose factorial needs to be found\n");
scanf("%d", &store_2);
//Mutex Initialisation
if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
{
    printf("\nMutex Initialisation has Failed\n");
    return 1;
}

//Creating Threads
pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &thread_1_And_2, &store_1);//For Sum
pthread_create(&id2, NULL, &thread_1_And_2, &store_2);//For Factorial


//Joining All Threads
pthread_join(id1, NULL);
pthread_join(id2, NULL);

//Destroying the Mutex
pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);


//Printing
printf("\n Output of Thread 1 is Sum = %d \n", sum);
printf("\n Output of Thread 2 is Factorial = %llu \n", fact);
```

Output:

```
Asking input for:
"Enter number upto which you want a sum of natural numbers"
Input Given: 5
Asking input for:
"Enter number whose factorial needs to be found"
Input Given: 3
```

Now the Screen is Printing:

```
"I am in Thread 1"
"I am in Thread 2"
```

Pause for a while and then

```
Segmentation Fault: 11
```

I don't know what or where is it going wrong.

Comment: Where does it crash? And what output do you get?

Comment: If C++: use std::thread and not pthreads.

Comment: what is `store_1` and `store_2 initialized to? Are they int pointer?

Comment: @FredLarson
Its C not C++

Comment: Hi @LethalProgrammer Store_1 and 2 are taken in using scanf

Comment: I don't see `scanf()` in your code, please provide the entire code in-order to know the problem your facing.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and it will literally show you exactly where the fault occurs, and why. [tl;dr](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @LethalProgrammer added the scanf part as you said! Can you kindly help me now

Comment: @Useless how can I run a debugger using terminal?
I am using Sublime to write the code and running is via the terminal!

Comment: On Linux, by typing `gdb your-program-here`. On other *NIX, either using gdb or the native debugger, whichever is installed (or whichever matches your compiler).

Comment: @GauravSingh what output do you get???

Comment: @MichaelWalz It asked me to input the values as described by scanf()
Then it printed
"I am Thread 1: Processing Sum"
"I am Thread 2: Processing Factorial"

And then Segmentation Error: 11
When I am trying to print the value of Sum and Fact in the main

Comment: @GauravSingh please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: @MichaelWalz Done! Please check.

Comment: I didn't duplicate the seg fault with this code, but it seems to me that destroying your mutex before you join the threads is dangerous.

Comment: In addition, it seems to me that the mutex is unnecessary here, since the threads do not access anything in common. Rather, the mutex serves only to serialize the code, making the multithreading pointless.

Comment: @FredLarson that was a typo! I have actually joined before destroying! still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same program updated to use C++ `std::thread`s. The simpler program avoids the crash:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cstdio>

//Global Variables
int sum;
long long fact = 1;
//pthread_mutex_t lock;
std::mutex m;
//pthread_t id1, id2;
std::thread id1, id2;

//void *thread_1_And_2(void *accept_1)
void thread_1_And_2(int a)
{
    ////Accepting Input
    //int *a_ptr = (int*)accept_1;
    //int a = *a_ptr;

    //Locking the resource
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

    //Returning the process ID that is working right now!
    //pthread_t my_current_id;
    //my_current_id = pthread_self();
    std::thread::id my_current_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

    //if((pthread_equal(id1, my_current_id))>0)
    if(id1.get_id() == my_current_id)
    {

        printf("\nI am Thread 1: Processing Sum\n");

        printf("\n I am in Thread 1 \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    //else if((pthread_equal(id2, my_current_id))>0)
    else if(id2.get_id() == my_current_id)
    {
        printf("\nI am Thread 2: Processing Factorial\n");
        if(a < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Error! Factorial of Negative number not possible \n");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
            {
                fact = fact*i;
            }
        }
    }

    //Unlocking the Mutex
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // RAII will do this

    //return 0;
}

int main()
{
    ////Mutex Initialisation
    //if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    //{
    //    printf("\nMutex Initialisation has Failed\n");
    //    return 1;
    //}
    {

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

        //Creating Threads
        id1 = std::thread{[]() {thread_1_And_2(3); }};
        id2 = std::thread{[]() {thread_1_And_2(4); }};
        //pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &thread_1_And_2, &store_1);//For Sum
        //pthread_create(&id2, NULL, &thread_1_And_2, &store_2);//For Factorial

        //Destroying the Mutex
        //pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); // RAII will take care of the lock
    }

    id1.join();
    id2.join();
}
```

Comment: You are doing the exact same thing, like me. Just that you are using Cpp and I am using C
I have no clue why am I getting the Segmentation Fault Error